TypeScript Generic Class for DiscordJS Commands
I am currently working on a Discord Bot and I am kinda new to TypeScript and need some help with my command class...
This is my current class:
export class Command {
  constructor(
    public options: {
      ...
      data: ApplicationCommandData & {
        type: ApplicationCommandType;
        contexts?: Context[];
        integration_types?: IntegrationTypes[];
      };
      execute: (options: { client: DiscordClient; interaction: CommandInteraction }) => any;
      ...
    }
  ) {}
}

This is how to use it:
export default new Command({
  data: {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Replies with Pong!',
    type: ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
    contexts: [Context.GUILD, Context.BOT_DM, Context.PRIVATE_CHANNEL],
    integration_types: [IntegrationTypes.GUILD_INSTALL, IntegrationTypes.USER_INSTALL],
  },
  execute({ interaction}) {
    interaction.reply({ content: 'Pong!', ephemeral: true });
  },
});

The problem with this is that no matter what type (User, Message or ChatInput) the command is, the interaction will always be just be the base CommandInteraction and it's not possible to get string options (interaction.options.getString()) from it. I would have to put if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return; at the top of every ChatInputCommand that uses string options.
Now I need some help to create a generic class (if possible) to solve this issue. I want the type of my class/command to determine the interaction type of the execute function.
Here's a rough (not working) example of what I have in mind:
export class Command<Type> {
  constructor(
    public options: {
      ...
      data: ApplicationCommandData & {
        type: Type;
        contexts?: Context[];
        integration_types?: IntegrationTypes[];
      };
      execute: (options: { client: DiscordClient; interaction: interactions[type] }) => any;
      ...
    }
  ) {}
}

I want the type to be taken from the command.options.data.type property and use it to go through an interactions object/array to obtain the corresponding interaction for the type of command!
Please let me know if this is possible.
Otherwise I'll just have to make 3 classes for each type of command (User, Message, ChatInput)...
I tried lots of different stuff but in the end I could not find a solution.

Solved this with the help of ChatGPT
This is my new Class:
import {
  ApplicationCommandType,
  AutocompleteInteraction,
  ChatInputCommandInteraction,
  MessageContextMenuCommandInteraction,
  UserContextMenuCommandInteraction,
  type RESTPostAPIApplicationCommandsJSONBody,
} from 'discord.js';
import { DiscordClient } from './client';

export enum Contexts {
  GUILD = 0,
  BOT_DM = 1,
  PRIVATE_CHANNEL = 2,
}

export enum IntegrationTypes {
  GUILD_INSTALL = 0,
  USER_INSTALL = 1,
}

type InteractionType<T extends ApplicationCommandType> = T extends ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput
  ? ChatInputCommandInteraction
  : T extends ApplicationCommandType.Message
  ? MessageContextMenuCommandInteraction
  : T extends ApplicationCommandType.User
  ? UserContextMenuCommandInteraction
  : never;

export class Command<T extends ApplicationCommandType = ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput> {
  constructor(
    public options: {
      developerOnly?: boolean; // If command is for developer only, it cannot be used by anyone else
      cooldown?: number; // Cooldown between command executes per user (in milliseconds)
      data: RESTPostAPIApplicationCommandsJSONBody & {
        type: T;
        contexts?: Contexts[];
        integration_types?: IntegrationTypes[];
      };
      autocomplete?: (options: { client: DiscordClient; interaction: AutocompleteInteraction }) => any;
      execute: (options: { client: DiscordClient; interaction: InteractionType<T> }) => any;
    }
  ) {}
}

And it automatically gives me correct interaction type for my interactions depending on what type the command is.
Here's an example of a ChatInputCommand and a UserContextMenuCommand:
import { ActionRowBuilder, ApplicationCommandType, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, Colors, EmbedBuilder } from 'discord.js';

import { Command, Contexts, IntegrationTypes } from 'classes/command';

export default new Command({
  data: {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Replies with Pong!',
    type: ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
    contexts: [Contexts.GUILD, Contexts.BOT_DM, Contexts.PRIVATE_CHANNEL],
    integration_types: [IntegrationTypes.GUILD_INSTALL, IntegrationTypes.USER_INSTALL],
  },
  async execute({ interaction, client }) {
    const sent = await interaction.reply({ content: 'Pinging...', fetchReply: true });

    await interaction.editReply({
      content: '',
      embeds: [
        new EmbedBuilder()
          .setColor(Colors.Blurple)
          .setTitle(i18next.t('Pong!', { lng }))
          .addFields(
            { name: 'Websocket Hearbeat', value: `${client.ws.ping}` },
            { name: 'Roundtrip Latency', value: `${sent.createdTimestamp - interaction.createdTimestamp}ms` }
          ),
      ],
    });
  },
});

import { ApplicationCommandType, Colors, EmbedBuilder } from 'discord.js';

import { Command, Contexts, IntegrationTypes } from 'classes/command';

export default new Command({
  data: {
    name: 'Avatar & Banner',
    type: ApplicationCommandType.User,
    contexts: [Contexts.GUILD, Contexts.BOT_DM, Contexts.PRIVATE_CHANNEL],
    integration_types: [IntegrationTypes.GUILD_INSTALL, IntegrationTypes.USER_INSTALL],
  },
  async execute({ interaction, client }) {
    await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });

    try {
      const user = await client.users.fetch(interaction.targetId, { force: true });
      if (!user) return interaction.editReply('Could not find user');

      const member = await interaction.guild?.members.fetch(user.id);

      const embeds: EmbedBuilder[] = [
        new EmbedBuilder()
          .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 4096 })),
      ];
      if (user.banner)
        embeds.push(
          new EmbedBuilder()
            .setImage(user.bannerURL({ size: 4096 })!)
        );
      if (member && member.avatar)
        embeds.push(
          new EmbedBuilder()
            .setImage(member.displayAvatarURL({ size: 4096 }))
        );

      interaction.editReply({ embeds });
    } catch (err) {
      interaction.editReply('Something went wrong');
    }
  },
});

For more of the source code,
check out my GitHub repository:
https://github.com/CuteNikki/discord-bot
